# Aligning text centered on left margin; mystery horizontal space

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc, expl3, xparse}

\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\globalsettoheight{\@gsettodim\ht}
\def\globalsettodepth {\@gsettodim\dp}
\def\globalsettowidth {\@gsettodim\wd}

\def\@gsettodim#1#2#3{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}\global#2#1\@tempboxa
  \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}

\newlength\length@interviewer
\newlength\length@interviewee
\newlength\length@sep

\settowidth\length@sep{:\hspace{1em}}

\NewDocumentCommand\interviewer { m m } {
  \globalsettowidth   \length@interviewer { #1 }

  % Display the full name and then globally redefine to initials,
  % updating the length accordingly.
  \def                      \@interviewer {
    #1
    \global\def             \@interviewer { #2 }
    \globalsettowidth \length@interviewer { #2 }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\interviewee { m m } {
  \globalsettowidth   \length@interviewee { #1 }

  % Display the full name and then globally redefine to initials,
  % updating the length accordingly.
  \def                      \@interviewee {
    #1
    \global\def             \@interviewee { #2 }
    \globalsettowidth \length@interviewee { #2 }
  }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { question } { m } {
  \par\noindent
  \hspace{-\length@interviewer}
  \hspace{-\length@sep}
  \textsc{\@interviewer}:
  \hspace{1em}
  #1
  \vspace{1ex}

  \par\noindent
  \hspace{-\length@interviewee}
  \hspace{-\length@sep}
  \textsc{\@interviewee}:
  \hspace{1em}
  \ignorespaces
} {
  \vspace{3ex}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\interviewer{Jane Doe}{JD}
\interviewee{John Smith}{JS}

\setlength\parindent{3em}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}{Sample Question?}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{question}
\begin{question}{Sample Question?}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{question}
\begin{question}{Sample Question?}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following output:

[image: output]

Why is the first use misaligned?
Where is the extra space coming from?
(Feel free to `expl3`-ify the code if it burns the eyes—I had to adapt it to make it more readable so that I could try and figure this out.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are storing an unformatted version of the interviewer and interviewee, yet you're setting a formatted version (using `\textsc`) in your document. You also use this unformatted version to measure the length, which is causing the misalignment.

I've fixed this by using the following definitions of `\interviewer` and `\interviewee`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\interviewer { m m } {
  \globalsettowidth   \length@interviewer { \scshape #1 }% Updated with formatting

  % Display the full name and then globally redefine to initials,
  % updating the length accordingly.
  \def                      \@interviewer {
    #1
    \global\def             \@interviewer { #2 }
    \globalsettowidth \length@interviewer { #2 }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\interviewee { m m } {
  \globalsettowidth   \length@interviewee { \scshape #1 }% Updated with formatting

  % Display the full name and then globally redefine to initials,
  % updating the length accordingly.
  \def                      \@interviewee {
    #1
    \global\def             \@interviewee { #2 }
    \globalsettowidth \length@interviewee { #2 }
  }
}
```

[image]

However, I would suggest defining a suitable macro that stores the formatting of the interviewer and interviewee, respectively. For example,

```
\providecommand{\@interviewerfont}{\normalfont}
\providecommand{\@intervieweefont}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\interviewerfont}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\@interviewerfont}{#1}}
\newcommand{\intervieweefont}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\@intervieweefont}{#1}}
```

and then place these in the appropriate locations in your `\interviewer` and `\interviewee` definitions.